# Removing .Diffuse colours from an FBX model

Tags: c#, xna, augmented-reality, game-development

I am currently working on an AR project, based around the original 'Tutorial 8 - Marker Tracking' program supplied by GoblinXNA. I've had a play around with it, and replaced the models with some of my own designs, saved as .fbx format. The problem I am having though is that the .Diffuse extension is replacing the the original colours of the model with red; altering the colours makes no difference, only changing the colour and not allowing me to have the models original appearance, and removing the .Diffuse line of code only makes the model turn to shades of grey and black (I'm guessing this is something to do with CreateLights() method?)

In any case, here is the code form the object; any help would be much appreciated!

```
    ModelLoader mLoader = new ModelLoader(); //self explanatory
    Model flagModel = (Model)mLoader.Load("", "FlagModelAsset2");

    flagNode = new GeometryNode("FlagModelAsset2");
    flagNode.Model = flagModel;
    flagNode.AddToPhysicsEngine = true;
    flagNode.Physics.Shape = ShapeType.Box;
    flagNode.Model.ShadowAttribute = ShadowAttribute.ReceiveCast;
    flagNode.Model.Shader = new SimpleShadowShader(scene.ShadowMap);

    //TransformNode flagTransNode = new TransformNode();
    //flagTransNode.Translation = new Vector3(0, 0, 0); //position of flag
    //flagTransNode.Scale = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f); //size of flag

    toolbarMarkerNode = new MarkerNode(scene.MarkerTracker, "ALVARToolbar.xml");

    Material flagMaterial = new Material();
    flagMaterial.Diffuse = new Vector4(0.5f, 2, 0, 1); //colour of flag
    flagMaterial.Specular = Color.White.ToVector4();
    flagMaterial.SpecularPower = 10;

    flagNode.Material = flagMaterial;

    groundMarkerNode.AddChild(flagNode);
    scene.RootNode.AddChild(toolbarMarkerNode);
    //flagNode.AddChild(flagTransNode);            


    NewtonPhysics.CollisionPair pair = new NewtonPhysics.CollisionPair(flagNode.Physics, sphereNode.Physics);
    ((NewtonPhysics)scene.PhysicsEngine).AddCollisionCallback(pair, BoxSphereCollision);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the materials; removing this and adding the code below allows the use of the textures from the original imported file

```
((Model)flagNode.Model).UseInternalMaterials = true;
```